# insert values with \"%s\ error MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i want to insert array to mysql db using php..

and now i getting error with this code :

```
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO detail_paket (id_paket, menu_paket) select
 paket.id,\'%s\' from paket where paket.nama_paket='$nama_paket'",%data1[$i]);
            ^
            |   
   here is the error syntax
```

*data1* is the array..

what is the correct syntax to use *\'%s\'* ?

when i trying to run the query, the error info show : *syntax error, unexpected '%' in* **or** *syntax error* unexpected "" in*.

i already tried using \"%s\ and \"%s"\ and %s and '%s' and "%s" and \"%s\" but the query still give me error..

and one last question, what is this '**%s**' syntax called  ?

thanks...

**original query from tutorial**

```
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO student (first_name, last_name) VALUES(\"%s\",\"%s\")",
      $student_record[$i][0], $student_record[$i][1]);
```

Comment: no need to wrap `%s` with `'` and `%s` means string value

Comment: @SashiKant i need to insert an array, the tutorial teach me to use this %s syntax..but i modified it a bit and the query give me error.

Comment: @GBD still didnt work..the error say syntax error, unexpected '%'.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `%` and change the `%` prefix of `data1` to `$`:

```
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO detail_paket (id_paket, menu_paket) select paket.id,%s from paket where paket.nama_paket='$nama_paket'",$data1[$i]);
```

The other problem is you need to separate the two queries with a `;`. This won't work on all MySQL APIs, not all of them allow multiple queries. You might need to run two queries instead of a single multiple query.

Comment: the data is not inserted.i added the original tutorial code if your want have a look.

Comment: @ChristianWibowo see my edit. Multiple queries doesn't work on all APIs.

Comment: i see.so the first query is to get the id_paket, then pass it to second query where the values are inserted ?

Comment: The first query is trying to INSERT but, it doesn't have any values to insert. The tutorial query looks a lot different to yours....

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it this way, you can replace '%s' with '{$data1[$i]}' and get rid of the sprintf. Although I think it is more secure to use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: like this : _$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO detail_paket (id_paket, menu_paket) select paket.id,'$data1[$i]' from paket where paket.nama_paket='$nama_paket'";_ ?

Comment: Just noticed you're trying to substitute a column name with a variable, this should do it too `INSERT INTO detail_paket (id_paket, menu_paket) select paket.id, {$data1[$i]} from paket where paket.nama_paket='$nama_paket'` although @MrCode's solution would be more appropriate